# how to upload blobs recorded by mediastreamrecorder in youtube using youtubeapi using javascript

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, webrtc, youtube-javascript-api

i am recording video through mediastreamrecorder.js. Video is recording perfectly in blobs of 5 seconds in ondataavailable function.
e.g here
this is in index.html where i am getting auth signin etc.

```
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
                blob=blob;
            };
```

i am getting auth correctly but don't know how can i trigger initiateupload  or resumeupload function of youtubeapi's upload js file after every blob come from html file.
please help

Answer (score -1):

[MediaStreamRecorder.js](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) not only provides intervals based blobs; but full-length blob as well. Here is how to get full-length blob:

```
var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
    Upload_Full_Length_Blob_To_Youtube(blob);

    // or upload array-buffer
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        Upload_Full_Length_Buffer_To_Youtube(event.target.result);

        // or if youtube supports Typed-Arrays
        var unit8Array = new Unint8Array(event.target.result);
        Upload_Full_Unit8Array_To_Youtube(unit8Array);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    // readAsBinaryString
    // readAsDataURL
    // readAs-------
};
mediaRecorder.start(999999999999999999999); // longest possible!

document.getElementById('stop-and-upload').onclick = function() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
};
```

Comment: But this will require more time for uploading. Is it possible to upload data as it come in blobs of 5 seconds synchronously during recording till stop button is clicked and full video uploaded at the end. If it is possible then please tell me how can i do that.

Comment: @MuhammadZafarNaeem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API#Capturing_the_media_stream